# PHP, arrays misunderstanding

Tags: php

please I'm preoccupied with a small problem that is how associative arrays in PHP are created in the memory(RAM),for example and to my C's language knowledge we talk about adresse and value into the memory, so how does php operate into memory?

Comment: The easiest for you is to treat them as a hash tables.

Comment: Might help: http://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html

Comment: You can also take a look at PHP's source to get an exact answer; try [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/spl/spl_fixedarray.c) or [here](https://github.com/php/php-src)

Comment: It's implementation-dependent. You need to know this only if you're planning to develop for Zend Engine or other PHP interpretator directly.

Comment: really you confused me ; what I exactly want to say is could a case of memory store more than a character in php because what I know in c's language that when we create a string: (char var[]="this is a string")